# PDF unable to download on browser when i hit my spring boot API from angular

Tags: java, spring-boot, download, pdf-generation

this is my controller method to download created PDF from html -

```
@PostMapping("/downloadPdf/{apiGroup}/{api}")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> generatePdf(@PathVariable String apiGroup, @PathVariable String api, HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp){
    
    Response response = new Response();
    LoggerDto loggerDto = new LoggerDto();
    loggerDto.setMessage("Inside generatePdf of DocumentGenerationController" );
    logger.printLog(DbEnum.INFO,loggerDto);
    
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream pdfStream = documentGenerationService.generatePdf(req, resp, apiGroup, api, loggerDto, logger);
        if(pdfStream != null){
            loggerDto.setMessage("PDF stream returned from DocumentGeneratorUtil" );
            logger.printLog(DbEnum.INFO,loggerDto);
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+api+".pdf");
    
            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .headers(httpHeaders)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                    .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfStream));
```

When I am hitting this API, PDF does not get downloaded on browser.

In response header I get below data :

Content-Disposition:
attachment; filename=Generate Quick invoice.pdf

Content-Type:
application/octet-stream

Comment: Have you checked the default downloads folder?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/generatepdf", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity generatepdf(
    final HttpServletResponse response
) throws IOException {
    final String headerKey = CONTENT_DISPOSITION;
    final String headerValue = "attachment; filename="foo.pdf";
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    // Write what you want in the: response.getOutputStream()

    response.flushBuffer();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```